# iOS 8 custom UIFont does not appear in fontFamily listing even though it shows in IB

Tags: ios, truetype, custom-font

in iOS 8, Xcode6, I add a custom font, in info.plist.  It's there in Build Phases.  It's there in the storyboard, but it does not list in familyNames.  I've read every other Stack Overflow post on this several times.

The file is CODBARD.TTF.  The actual postscript name is codabard.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", family);

        for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
        {
            NSLog(@"  %@", name);
        }
}
```

It's not there.

And this line of code just produces a nil result

```
UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"codabard" size:20];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use that font somewhere in a xib or storyboard

I create a blank xib and add labels which use the desired font, than i don't use the xib nowhere, but this loads the custom fonts